# Using swap in R

Tags: r, dplyr, swap

I'm trying to join two tables that are ~100 MB more than a previous successful attempt.

This is what I tried:

```
left_join(A, B, by = c("col_1","col_2","col_3"))
```

And I get

```
Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y, check_na_matches(na_matches)) : 
  std::bad_alloc
```

Meaning that I'm out of RAM.

Have you bypassed a similar issue like using swap instead of RAM?

Comment: Swap and RAM are more or less indistinguishable from a user-space point-of-view.

Comment: If your data is expanding that much from a left join, either your keys are really not unique and are getting crossed, or they contain `NA`s which dplyr joins cross by default on data.frames (like `merge`). The new 0.7 version adds a `na_matches` parameter you can set to `"never"` to make them behave like database joins or `merge` with `incomparables = FALSE`.

Comment: Use AWS EC2 & S3. You'll likely spend $5-10.00 USD total.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I increased swap partion size in linux and that prevented before common R crashes with error message "bad_alloc" caused by RAM shortage.

I increased the partion from 8 GB to 16 GB size in Ubuntu using gparted application (Before I had created linux-swap also using gparted). Increasing only the partion size was not enough but also following steps were required to make changes in effect:

- I had to right click the created partition and click "swapon".
- I had check the UUID identity code clicking *information* in the window of previous step (Running *blkid* on command line also gives the information).
- I had to edit line with text "swap" in the file */etc/fstab* to include the UUID code found out in the previous step.
- I rebooted system.

**WARNING:** This solution might be at cost of a somewhat shorter lifespan of the SSD ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652337/why-no-swap-partitions-on-ssd-drives)). So if it is possible to increase physical RAM memory in the system increasing RAM might be preferred solution but also with a cost, monetary one.